# Correspondence principle and pigeonhole principle problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question** : Using $prime$ $factorization$ show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the divisors of $900$ and the Cartesian product $A \times A \times A$, where $A = \{0,1,2\}$. Use this fact to count the number of divisors of $900$.

I know that the prime factorization of $900$ is $2^2 \times 3^2 \times 5^2$  and the Cartesian product is $27$. But I can't quite understand what the question is asking? help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every factor of $900$ is in the form $2^a 3^b 5^c$. The Cartesian product will return 27 sets of $A \times A \times A$, in which each $A$ represents $a$, $b$, or $c$ from $\{0,1,2\}$. Since $a, b, c$ can only be from $0$ to $2$ for a factor of $900$, the Cartesian product is a 1 to 1 correspondence to the factors of $900$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is asking for a one-to-one correspondence--in other words, a paring--between the factors of $900$ and the elements of $A \times A \times A$.
By prime factorization, any factor of $900$ will look like $2^a 3^b 5^c$, where $0 \le a,b,c \le 2$. Therefore, the one-to-one correspondence you are looking for is
$$
2^a 3^b 5^c \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad (a,b,c)
$$
For example, one factor of $900$ is the number $90$.  Note that $90 = 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1$.
So $90$ will be paired with $(1, 2, 1)$, which is an element of $A \times A \times A$.